# Display as checkbox from database value (1 / 0)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am building a website for user privilage setting. I use ASP MVC for programming.
In my Database, I have column admin_privilage and user_privilage with value either 1/0.

Here is the screen and the code

```
<td>@item.admin_privilage</td>
<td>@item.user_privilage</td>
```

[image: screen]

What I want to do is to display it as a checkbox. If the value is true, then displayed as checked box. if false, then displayed as unchecked box.

[image]

anyone can help how to do this in asp mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @CheckBox HTML helper, like this:

```
<td>@Html.CheckBox("admin_privilage",item.admin_privilage)</td>
<td>@Html.CheckBox("user_privilage",item.user_privilage)</td>
```

Comment: the code is invalid. The name 'CheckBox' does not exist in current context

Comment: Its `@Html.ChackBox(...)` although you really should be using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` inside a `for` loop

Comment: @RaspiSurya ,I updated my answer, the 'Html' was missing

Comment: Use strongly-typed helpers: `foreach (var item in Model.Something) { <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.admin_privilege)</td><td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.user_privilege)</td> }`.